# Can google API use .NET dlls

Tags: google-api

I have a .NET dll which wraps SQL data base to query the data base.
The data in SQL has to be displayed in Google spreadsheet using this .NET dll.
Is there a way to call .NET dll in Google spreadsheet?

Comment: Even if there was a way to upload your DLL how would Google Spreadsheet on the Google Servers access your database?? Or did you mean run it client-side in JavaScript? I think your best bet is to write a web-service that does the database access that and try to get Google Spreadsheet to call into that. But to be clear, is it a spreadsheet you're trying to set up or a Google App Engine application? You've tagged this GAE

Comment: Probably web-service is the right approach for my scenario. I'm trying to set up spreadsheet, i couldn't find that tag neither could i create one, so i used Google App Engine. Please provide some links to use web-service with google spreadsheet.

Comment: Google Spreadsheet functions for external data http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75507 and an example http://blog.ouseful.info/2008/10/17/viewing-campaign-finance-data-in-a-google-spreadsheet-via-the-new-york-times-campaign-data-api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a web service  with microsoft azure (microsofts cloud computing platform). You google app can then call that web service and can way use your dll's this way.